# Wie sagt man "gang signs"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Wenn Gangster sich treffen, zeigen sie sich ihre Gangsterzeichen als Erkennung, indem sie entweder Buchstaben mit ihren Fingern formen oder einander die Hand schütteln und dann die Körper gegeneinander schlagen.

Ich weiß nicht, ob das Wort "Gangsterzeichen" in diesem Kontext richtig ist.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what type of gang signs? A special handshake, a gesture, a tattoo, do they flash their bellies? The context might be required here.

Comment: "Gangster" is rather old-fashioned and does not mean the same thing as a gang member („Gang-Mitglied“). I would simply go with „Gang-Zeichen“, no need to translate "gang".

Comment: Gibts nicht in Deutschland. Hier gibts auch keine Gangs und Gangster. Hier sind alle lieb und sagen "Guten Tag". ;)

Comment: @Vogel6121 sorry for the mistakes. I don't know how to make it right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As linac pointed out in his [comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9948/wie-sagt-man-gang-signs#comment25587_9948), the word *Gangmitglied* or *Gang-Mitglied* is more appropriate than *Gangster*, which has a different connotation. The word you are most likely look for to translate gang sign, would be

> Erkennungszeichen

which translates to "sign of identification/recognition".

Comment: Danke! Das ist sehr hilfreich.

Comment: Du solltest Deine Antwort auf das konzentrieren, was der Frager wissen wollte, nicht auf evtl. Fehler in der Frage. Die könnten später korrigiert werden, und dann ist Deine Antwort veraltet. Korrekturen können mittels Kommentar vorgeschlagen/diskutiert werden. Mit genügend Reputation kann man bei eigener Sicherheit die Frage selbt korrigieren. Zur Diskussion dazu auf Meta http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/331/spelling-mistakes-in-questions diese Frage, die aber leider vandalisiert wurde.

Comment: @userunknown Danke, gucke ich mir an!